# Keep mac desktops in place?

Tags: macos, mac, macbook

When you have several desktops open, with each program in a different one, let's say Firefox in Desk 1 and Finder in Desk 5. When you open a file in Finder that opens in Firefox, it moves desk 5 all the way over to desk two, shifting everything backwards.

How do you keep this in place so that opening files will open in their programs like normal, but never shift the desktops out of order?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I hope I got your question right... You can prevent desktops from rearranging in System Preferences.

Open the Mission Control preference pane:

[image]

and **unselect** option "Automatically rearrange spaces based on most recent use":

[image]

The other options provide further customization.

Comment: This appears to do the trick. I very much appreciate your help.