# MacBook Pro (2019, 16 inch) keeps switching/rearranging my 2 external monitors

Tags: mac, display, docking-station

I use a CalDigit dock for my macbook but every other time I plug my mac into my CalDigit dock (via USB-C) port, it switches my external monitors around.

I have my MacBook set in the center, and monitors to the left and right of my MacBook but then as shown below, it'll re-arrange the monitors once I plug in:

[image: Rearranged displays]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mac: 3 monitor setup: My desktop set keep switching places between monitors](https://superuser.com/questions/1105308/mac-3-monitor-setup-my-desktop-set-keep-switching-places-between-monitors)

Comment: Is it possible to simply switch the cables or the location of the screens? If the computer thinks it's always this way, going along with what the computer thinks is a simple fix.